# Highlights keep showing from previous version on Kindle

Tags: kindle

I don't have a Kindle, otherwise I would have tested this: is it possible that when updating (manually, through Calibre or some other programs) a book that already has some highlight, those highlights keep showing on the new version? The files presumably have the same filename and the same title/authors, if that helps.

Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK, highlights are kept in a separate text file, https://blog.the-ebook-reader.com/2014/09/25/how-to-export-edit-kindle-notes-and-highlights/ . Delete that file.